# Where do Ubuntu wallpapers come from?

Tags: desktop-background, 24.04

Where do Ubuntu wallpapers come from? Are they submitted by the community or created privately by specialists? If they are submitted by the community, do they keep all the wallpapers or only some? Can I submit my own art?

Comment: i Googled **ubuntu 24.04 Wallpaper Contest** and found [ubuntu 24.04 Wallpaper Contest](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2024/02/ubuntu-24-04-wallpaper-contest/). What are the odds of that!?! Does it answer all your questions?

Comment: Thank you, @user68186. It does.

Comment: The actual announcement and all the submissions are in [here](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-24-04-wallpaper-competition/42300).

Comment: Thanks a million!

Comment: Don't forget there are also *flavors* which have their own procedures, eg. also found at the *Ubuntu Community Hub* is the [Ubuntu Studio 24.04 LTS Wallpaper Competition](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-studio-24-04-lts-wallpaper-competition/42528).  Flavors have accepted direct submissions too, eg. [this thread](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/made-a-new-wallpaper-with-lubuntu-logo/2650/) shows a submission '*out of the blue*' with some used for a coming release. Some *flavors* do have specific creators who submit work every six months (pre-release) etc so it varies.

Comment: Thank you, @guiverc.